# Continually take input, and add values of input to a variable after keyword

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming, and am taking a C++ class. Here's my assignment:

```
Write a program that continually takes in input until the user types “done”.
When the input received is a “+”, start adding together the values of each
subsequent input into a variable. When the input is a “-”, start subtracting
the values of the subsequent input from that same variable. Do nothing with
inputs that are received before either a “+” or “-” operation. Output the
final result to the screen.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    int number;
    vector<int> numbers;

    cout << "Type some stuff: \n";


    for (;cin >> input && input != "done";)
    {
        if (input == "done")
            break;
        else if (input == "+")

        cout << input;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Type some stuff: 
Hello world done
HelloworldProgram ended with exit code: 0
```

I can't figure out the next part though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please edit your post with sample input and corresponding (expected) output.

Comment: Is the input text or numeric?  You code is assuming numbers and text (the numbers are saved).

Comment: Use `ostringstream` to convert from text to numeric.  This will also fail if the text is not numeric.

Comment: Hint: don't collect inputs in a vector but calculate (intermediate) result immediately; Use a "currentMode", which is `0` at the beginning, `+1` after a `+`-input, and `-1` after a `-`-input. Convert other inputs to numbers (e.g. by using `atoi(...)`), and multiply with `currentMode`. Add this to intermediate result...

Comment: Interesting question wording. What if the user does not continuously provide input? Does the program fail?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added the output. Also, I'm assuming the input is supposed to be both text and numbers. Once a '+' or  '-' is entered, I'm supposed to start doing math on the subsequent entered numbers.

Comment: @StephanLechner But how do you do that in the middle of a string that also includes chars?

Comment: You should show example input and expected output.  I suspect that the `+` and `-` commands are expected to appear on a separate line.  My gut would be to read the input with `std::getline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the assignment one can assume that inputs are words/numbers separated by a white space. The code line `for (;cin >> input && input != "done";)`, which I suppose to be given as part of the assignment, supports this assumption. Then, the following input is supposed to achieve the following output:

```
100 200 + 100 200 - 10 done  --> 290
```

Here's the code to achieve this:

```
int main()
{
    string input;
    int result;
    int mode = 0;

    cout << "Type some stuff: \n";


    for (;cin >> input && input != "done";)
    {
        if (input == "done")
            break;
        else if (input == "+")
            mode = 1;
        else if (input == "-")
            mode = -1;
        else {
            try {
                int number = stoi(input);
                number *= mode;
                result += number;
            }
            catch( const std::exception& e ) {  }  // ignore any conversion errors
        }
    }

    cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```